# How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, lastpage

I want to add a footer to my document displaying the current number out of total number of pages. How do I do that?

Comment: Good answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646292/4736

Answer (score 227, accepted):

I have not tried, but I found this at some old .tex files:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
...
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is the method recommended within _The LaTeX Compantion_.

Comment: When using the Ruby rtex gem with Rails, this wasn't working for me at first. Then I added `:preprocess => true` to my rails controller render block and all is good! `render :filename => "schedule.pdf", :preprocess => true, :file => 'document.pdf.rtex', :content_type => 'application/pdf', :processor => "pdflatex -shell-escape"` I had read somewhere that using `\pageref` requires running `latex` twice.

Comment: @Docunext: Using `lastpage` does require two passes --- `latex` has no way to know how many pages a document will contain until it has had the chance to compile the document.

Comment: Minor mod, to get the right spacing, \thepage\~of~\pageref{LastPage}}

Comment: Note that `\usepackage{hyperref}` is incompatible with this.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton `\~of` results in õf, that's probably not intended.

Comment: that second backspace was a typo. oops.

Comment: @DavidZ When I use \usepackage{lastpage} \fancyfoot[C]{name {\thepage}~of~\pageref{LastPage}} I get this error:LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 99.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 2 undefined on input line 147.

[2]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 3 undefined on input line 189.

[3]

Package lastpage Warning: Rerun to get the references right on input line 207.


! Package lastpage Error: No auxiliary file allowed.

Comment: In addition to `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`, `\pagestyle{fancy}` or `\thispagestyle{fancy}` are needed.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou `\pagestyle{fancy}` works for me, but not `\thispagestyle{fancy}`. I'm using `scrartcl`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha You shouldn't use this at all with KOMA classes.

Comment: One more useful note: to make the number **black**, use \pageref*{LastPage}

Comment: @jontejj Could you elaborate? Why do you think this is incompatible with the `hyperref` package? The other answers suggest otherwise and recommend that you use `\pageref*{LastPage}` instead if you want to remove the link.

Comment: @BenUsman What you are referring to is that the starred version (with the asterisk) tells the `hyperref` package *not* to make a link from the page number and thus the number is displayed as normal text, which often is black.

Comment: Using the 'fancy' option on `fancyhdr` seems to add a horizontal line in the header. If I change it to 'plain', the line disappears, but so does the Page X of Y. Any ideas?

Comment: how to add the last page to the first/title page? I need 1 of Y in the first page, but it's not applying there

Answer (score 93):

If the document just contains arabic page numbers, probably the [lastpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package is your friend:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
...
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

If the document consists of e.g. X (ten) pages with Roman numbers in the front matter, 100 pages with arabic numbers in the main matter, and K (eleven) pages with alphabetical "numbered" pages in the back matter, `\pageref{LastPage}` will give "K", the name of the last page. If instead "121" (=10+100+11) shall be shown, the [pageslts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) package can be used:

```
\usepackage{pageslts}
...
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage) of \lastpageref{LastPages}}
```

which e.g. for page "B" in the backmatter would print "Page B (112) of 121".
pageslts offers a lot of additional possibilities (probably "overkill" for a document with only arabic numbers).

When there is output via `\AtEndDocument`, `\pageref{LastPage}` of the lastpage package will not include that output, if that was placed `\AtEndDocument` after loading the package.
If you want to reference the very last page, `\lastpageref{VeryLastPage}` of pageslts package can be used.

If `\addtocounter{page}{...}` or `\setcounter{page}{...}` is used, "LastPage does not give the total number of pages (even if arabic is the page numbering scheme of that page). (The pageslts package puts `\lastpageref{LastPages}` (with s at the end) at your disposal for remediation: LastPages ignores page number manipulation.)" (from the lastpage documentation).

If the last page uses the fnsymbol page numbering scheme, lastpage could get problems. (pageslts should work.)

Generally for generating "page ... of ..." two compilation runs are required. Depending on other packages, even more migt be necessary. See for any rerun messages at the end of the log-file.

If the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package is used, but `\pageref{LastPage}` or `\lastpageref{LastPages}` shall not create a hyperlink, the starred forms are available: `\pageref*{LastPage}` and `\lastpageref*{LastPages}`.

The lastpage and pageslts manuals also list some further alternatives:

- lastpage209.sty (also from the [lastpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package), for LaTeX 2.09
- [pageslts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) (as mentioned above)
- [totpages](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totpages)
- [totcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totcount) used with the page counter
- nofm.sty (if anyone would be able to find a working version thereof) ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex209/contrib/misc/nofm.sty,
- [count1to](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/count1to)
- [zref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref), additionally requiring e-TeX (included in all modern TeX distributions), "but if you already have e-TeX, you may have a look at the extensive zref package, whether it suits your needs better (or additionally or whatsoever)" (lastpage documentation again).

And [Brent.Longborough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document/32498#32498) additionally mentioned here the memoir package providing `\thelastpage` and `\thelastsheet`.

(If the question was "How do you add “page # of ##” on your document?" this would be a CW question...)

Comment: This is an excellent answer and summarizes all the issues very well.

Comment: I use the `totpages` package you reference. The total # of pages is invoked with `\ref{TotPages}`.

Answer (score 28):

[The *memoir* class](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) provides `\thelastpage` and `\thelastsheet` from their respective counters, depending on your precise needs.

Comment: So with `memoir` one normally doesn't need `lastpage` or `pageslts`, correct?

Comment: @LoverofStructure : That's correct.

Comment: This is very useful as I am using memoir class for my books, so its better to have less external dependencies. Thanks for this method.

Comment: @Brent Longborough: MWE would be nice.

Answer (score 25):

There is an alternative to the `lastpage` provided by the `zref` package. It has a `lastpage` module which provides the same functionality using the modern `zref` way to make references.
Simply use `\zpageref{LastPage}` instead of `\pageref{LastPage}`.

For the minimal use-case this doesn't give any benefits, but with `zref` the number is not hyperlinked by default (if `hyperref` is loaded of course) and it also provides a `\ziflastpage{<refname>}{<true>}{<false>}` conditional to test if a certain label got placed on the last page. There are also further macros for package writers. See the `zref` manual for them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lastpage,user]{zref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \zpageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

The last page is \zpageref{LastPage}.

\newpage

...

\newpage

...

\newpage

on the last page

\end{document}
```

Comment: To suppres hyperlink to last page in `lastpage` one can use `\pageref*{LastPage}`.

Answer (score 20):

Sorry to add my late answer but this can be done without the use of any package, just by adding at the end a label `\label{LastPage}`. The total number of page being a `\pageref{LastPage}`.

Hey, but this doesn't work with complex page numbering ??!! Well, that's not true :

- One has to put the label at the end of the part where total page number is required.
- To prevent the label from escaping to the following part (ie jumping from main matter to back matter), I add some whitespaces after the label : `{LastPage}~`.

Here is a working example. I redefine frontmatter, mainmatter and backmatter because they are not present in the `article` class. This homemade solution should fit any needs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\newcommand{\frontmatter}{\clearpage \cfoot{\thepage\ }
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{Roman}}
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{\clearpage \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand{\backmatter}{\clearpage \cfoot{\thepage\ }
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{alph}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    The last page is \pageref{LastPageOfFrontMatter}.
    \newpage ... \newpage  ... \newpage
    on the last page of frontmatter
    \label{LastPageOfFrontMatter}~
\mainmatter
    The last page is \pageref{LastPage}.
    \newpage ... \newpage  ... \newpage
    on the last page of mainmatter
    \label{LastPage}~
\backmatter 
    The last page is \pageref{LastPageOfBackMatter}.
    \newpage ... \newpage  ... \newpage
    on the last page of backmatter
 \label{LastPageOfBackMatter}~
 \end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding loading yet another package. Nice if you want to keep it simple.

Comment: Very nice, and simple, and NO EXTRA PACKAGE

Comment: This is good additional information, but it does not provide the total number of pages for the whole document.

Answer (score 17):

Using the [`lastpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package, you can use the `\pageref{LastPage}` command to get the final page number of the document.

So the following code:

```
page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
```

would print "page # of ##" (where # is the current page number and ## is the final page number).

Answer (score 12):

You could also use the [`totalcount`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/totalcount) package as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage~of \totalpages}
\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a MWE using the `lastpage` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for mock text

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}% clear all fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you are using `\maketitle`, it issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`. The effect of this is that the first page numbering will remain `1`, rather than `1 of 2`. So you will need to redefine the `plain` pagestyle. Here is a MWE in that case.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for mock text

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Thanks to egreg for the explanation and code for this example.

Comment: +1 for solving first page `1 of x` inestead of `1`.

Comment: +1 thank you very much indeed, can you also show how to do this with the KOMA articles (they are clashing with fancyhdr)?

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm Probably not - I'm no expert. I suggest you ask another question on the site. If you want, you could ask on chat first, but they'll probably just tell you to ask a question.

Comment: what is % used for?

Comment: @DiegoS At the end of the line, it kills the carriage return character, or whatever the correct term is. Otherwise this is converted into `\par`, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it without the `fancyhdr` package, as [documented](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage/lastpage.pdf) in the `lastpage` package:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\hfil page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage}\hfil}
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I had to remove the `*` in `\pageref*{LastPage}` to make it work.

Comment: @rasul I didn't have to remove it, and it works for me,  Also `$evenhead` and `$oddhead` work analogously too!

Answer (score 5):

### In ConTeXt

```
\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]
\setupfootertexts[Page \currentpage\ of \lastpage]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a combination of the `total counter` and `associated counter` features from `xassoccnt` to achieve the total page count, even if the page numbers are reset or changed manually in between.

Finally, the output is done with `fancyhdr`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyfoot[C]{This is page \thepage\ of \TotalValue{totalpages} pages}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

There are \TotalValue{totalpages} pages in this document! % Should report 51 here!
\clearpage
% Generating 50 pages
\foreach \x in {1,...,50} {%
  \blindtext
  \clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Since version 1.2 of `xassoccnt` the package supports the `\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters` macro:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyfoot[C]{This is page \thepage\ of \TotalValue{totalpages} pages}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

There are \TotalValue{totalpages} pages in this document! % Should report 51 here!
\clearpage
% Generating 50 pages
\foreach \x in {1,...,50} {%
  \blindtext
  \clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should really rewrite this to answer the question. That is, provide a solution of the form Page ## of ###.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, I 'ignored' the `Page ## of ...###` for unknown reasons

Answer (score 2):

In plain TeX, we can use the `\lastpage` register when `opmac` is loaded.

```
\input opmac
\openref
\footline={\hss \rm \thefontsize[10]\the\pageno/\the\lastpage \hss}
```

Comment: On Debian `opmac` is hidden in the package `texlive-lang-czechslovak`. And it requires more than one TeX run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer as above. But simpler

`\usepackage{lastpage}`
...
You are on page `\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}`

Comment: How is this simpler than the identical answer above?

Comment: In this example, only the package and how to use it are shown.

Comment: I think my example would be easier for others to follow. Hence it is simpler.