# How do I add a Page X of Y in a KOMA-script class?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering

I saw the answers to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/791), but the accepted answer won't take effect in a KOMA-script class.

> ```
> \usepackage{lastpage}
> ...
> \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
> ```

I am using `scrartcl` and `lastpage`. The default page numbering is just the page number itself. I want it to be `currentPage / totalPages`. How do I modify it?

Comment: Another good answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577981/98645

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remember to specify the page style. This minimal example works, showing "2 of 3" etc. in the page foot:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
text
\newpage
text
\newpage
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: this time there is a page number on the upper right of each page. I only need the bottom "X of Y" numbering. How do I fix this?

Comment: found it. I added `\ohead{}` before `\cfoot...`

Comment: Note that `scrpage2` is obsolete. Simply replace `\usepacke{scrpage2}` by `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`. Additionally you can remove `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`.