# How do I make sure that \pageref{LastPage} doesn't get colored like the other links identified by hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, color, lastpage

I am using `hyperref` together with `lastpage`. My problem is that `\pageref{LastPage}` gets the same color as the links identified with `hyperref`. I want it to be just the ordinary color (e.g. black)

Allow me to adapt the chosen answer to [my previous question about `lastpage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4543/791):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            urlcolor=Maroon,
            linkcolor=Maroon}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\href{mailto:my_email@email.com}{my_email@email.com}

\newpage
text
\newpage
text
\end{document}
```

I tried `\usepackage{color}` and then modifying the `\cfoot...` line to `\cfoot{\thepage\ of \color{black}\pageref{LastPage}}`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use `\pageref*` as described in the [hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html).

Comment: (I made the assumption that you also do not want the page number of the last page to be a link.)

Answer (score 7):

In case you *do want*  the page number of the last page to be a link, you nearly got it: `\usepackage{color}` (or [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)) and

```
\cfoot{\thepage\ of {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\pageref{LastPage}}}
```

instead of

```
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \color{black}\pageref{LastPage}}
```

The additional brackets around the link to be coloured differently ensure that the colour change is local to this group, i.e. following links will be coloured Maroon (or whatsoever was chosen before) again.

Additionally you need to change `\href{mailto:my_email@email.com}{my_email@email.com}` to `\href{mailto:my_email@email.com}{my\_email@email.com}` and `Maroon` needs to be defined as colour.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @Jed: Yes, there seem to have been introduced some changes in the recent version of hyperref. Also `_` must be changed into `\_` and `Maroon` is no longer recognized. Thanks for pointing this out! I updated my answer.