# Trouble customising the footer on Chapter pages

Tags: header-footer

I'm writing a report and I've used the following line in the preamble

```
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt}/\hspace{1pt}$11$}
```

Everything is great except when I use     \chapter, because it turns it into the ordinary number of page, without writing page blabla/blabla

Coule you explain to me how i could correct this and make it write Page blabla / blabla even when i use a chapter ?

As requested the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt}/\hspace{1pt}$11$}

\begin{document}
text
\newpage
\chapter{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to change the page style used for chapter pages...  can you give us a complete (but minimal) example file?

Comment: Does this help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4543/15036

Comment: @Thruston It did not help sadly :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard classes, `\chapter`  sets the chapter page page style to `plain`, so you have to redefine it:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} %
 \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt}/\hspace{1pt}$11$}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt}/\hspace{1pt}$11$}

\begin{document}
text
\newpage
\chapter{text}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use page style `fancyplain`. Then it is easy to use the same content for plain and other pages using a `fancyhdr` page style:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}% option pdftex removed
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% do not load packages twice
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}% <- added

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\fancyplain{plain page}{other page}}% different contents for plain and other pages
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \hspace{1pt}/\hspace{1pt}\pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
text
\newpage
\chapter{text}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]