# How can I print “page # of ##” with the total page number in KOMA (scrlttr2)?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrlttr2, lastpage

[This questions explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/98645) how you can show the total page number of your document in the footer on each page, i.e. show a “page # of ##” instead of the default “page # of #”.

However, [even though someone asked for that in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document#comment1043446_282840), it does not explain how to do that in a KOMA class. It has been suggested to ask a new question.

I use `scrlttr2` for a letter, so I'd like to do the same.
So how can I do it there?

Comment: Why does the class matter? Your example simply uses `\usepackage{lastpage}` which should work with ´scrlttr2` as well.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, saw that too (I intitially voted to close it as a dupe), but the answer I got here also helps a lot as it is more detailled.

Comment: This is not a dupe, because `scrlttr2` provides its own solution. Additionally there could be more than one letter in a `scrlttr2` document.

Comment: @esdd Thanks yeah, given the nice answer, it is indeed different. And yeah, actually I use multiple letters in there with `mailmerge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple (without additional packages) redefine `\pagemark` to your needs:

```latex
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Foo}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{Bar}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext[15]
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also [helps for how you can put that on the first page, too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577981/98645). Thanks.

Comment: Ah wrong link, used: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578016/98645

Answer (score 1):

The `scrlttr2` class offers specific commands for modifying headers and footers, through the `scrlayer-scrpage` package. The mwe below is a starting point. Note that there is no need to use the `lastpage` package, as the class provides the internal `\lastletterpage` counter.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\cefoot{Page \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}
\cofoot{Page \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}
    
  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}

  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd add after reading the doc on this to use `\cfoot` instead of `\cefoot` and `\cofoot` unless you want different versions on unnumbered and numbered pages.