# page numbers should be of the form 4/7

Tags: page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add “page # of ##” on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document)

While submitting  Test paper in LaTeX,   I was asked to display page numbers as current page number out of total page numbers.

I am using article class.

For example it should look like:  1 out of 4, 2 out of 4, 3 out of 4 etc.
or 1/4,2/4 etc.

How to obtain it?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I add “page # of ##” on my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply use the `lastpage` package and use the following MWE to get the `1/3`, `2/3`, etc "look". If you want "out of" instead of "/", just replace `\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}` with `\thepage\ out of \pageref{LastPage}`. Be sure to compile the document twice to give LaTeX a chance to get the cross-referencing right.

Note that the code in the MWE doesn't require you to use any additional packages (such as `fancyhdr`) to manipulate the page headers and footers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,lastpage}  % 'lipsum' provides filler text
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfil \thepage/\pageref{LastPage} \hfil}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**: Should you be using the `hyperref` package as well, you may want to replace the instruction `\pageref` with `\pageref*`. The former command would instruct `hyperref` to make its argument into a hyperlink -- probably not an intended effect. The `hyperref` package provides the variant command `\pageref*` (as well as `\ref*` ...) to avoid creating hyperlinks out of the cross-reference.

Comment: It worked perfectly!

Comment: This does not work with the first page ...

Comment: @Hesam - May I ask you to be a bit more specific as to *what* doesn't work on the first page? Do you get an incorrect page number, or no "1 of nn" page marker, or is there another problem?

Comment: I only get "1", no "1 of X". It appears once you add \maketitle ...

Comment: @Hesam - Are you working with example code given in my answer, or are you working with your own document class and document setup? The reason I ask is that it looks like your document class is setting the page style of the title page separately from that of the other pages -- in which case my answer won't apply.

Comment: I already explained, in your example code above add \title{...} and \maketitle and the first page number becomes "1" not "1 of X".

Comment: @Hesam - Thanks for providing this explanation. The `\maketitle` macro of the `article` document class includes the instruction `\thispagestyle{plain}`, which undoes the redefinition of `\@oddfoot` of the MWE. If you use `\maketitle`, I suggest you load the `fancyhdr` package and follow the instructions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235/5001.