# Page numbering 143/141

Tags: page-numbering, lastpage

I have a large latex document, compiled with pdflatex. When it compiles (I compile twice, I have tried compiling thrice) the page numbers come out as:
1/141
2/141
...
142/141
143/141

On the bottom.It seems to be two numbers short. In the rest of the document the page numbers rise in order and all is fine.

What are the typical reasons for such a problem? Normally I know where to start trouble shooting, when it comes to this I am pretty lost.

Comment: Yes! Start by editing your question and adding an example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid the information you've provided so far is quite inadequate for the task of diagnosing what's going on. Do you have any commands that reset or otherwise affect the page counters? You mention "in the rest of the document" -- does this mean that `143/141` is shown on the final page and `142/143` on the penultimate page?

Comment: Yes, 142/143 in the penultimate page. No page counter commands.

I don't really know how to include more info. I have a 143+ page long document and no idea where the error may be. I only wonder who the likely suspects are ;)

Comment: I'll post the packages used.

Comment: The second number apparently comes from a faulty "lastpage" label - probably there are floats flushed out after the label. Do you use the lastpage package?

Comment: Related: [How can I add “page # of ##” on my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/5764)

Answer (score 15):

Package `lastpage` puts the label `LastPage` via `\AtEndDocument` at the end of the document. However, at the very end, LaTeX issues `\clearpage` that might cause float pages to be output after the label, see [Ulrike's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126444/page-numbering-143-141#comment284153_126444).

In this case, you can try package `zref-totpages` and use `\ztotpages` instead of `\pageref{LastPage}`. It uses the label `LastPage` of `zref-lastpage`. Instead of `\AtEndDocument` it uses the hook `\AfterLastShipout` of package `atveryend` that is called after the final `\clearpage` and before the `.aux` file is closed.