# Create new counter and give it a specific value

Tags: page-numbering, counters

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\def\hoejde{\calculate{3*\figurnummer}}
\def\bredde{\calculate{2*\figurnummer}}
\def\areal{\calculate{3*\figurnummer^2}}
\def\faktorA{\calculate{\hoejde+1}}
\def\faktorB{\calculate{\bredde+1}}
\def\faktorC{\calculate{\hoejde-1}}
\def\faktorD{\calculate{\figurnummer-1}}
\def\skalering{\calculate{1.9/\figurnummer}}

\def\betegn#1#2#3{%
  \rput(!#1 4 div \figurnummer mul #2 4 div \figurnummer mul){\small{$#3$}}
}

\def\figur#1{%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\def\figurnummer{#1 }
\centering
\psset{unit=\skalering}
\begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(\bredde,\hoejde)
    \pnodes{P}(\figurnummer,0)(0,\bredde)(\figurnummer,\hoejde)(\bredde,\bredde)
    \betegn{3}{7}{A}
    \betegn{3}{9}{B}
    \betegn{5}{9}{C}
    \betegn{5}{7}{D}
  {\psset{linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue}
    \multido{\iA=0+1}{\faktorA}{\psline(0,\iA)(\bredde,\iA)}
    \multido{\iB=0+1}{\faktorB}{\psline(\iB,0)(\iB,\hoejde)}}
   \psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \psline(P0)(P2)
    \psline(P1)(P3)
    \pspolygon[linejoin=2,linecolor=red](P0)(P1)(P2)(P3)
  \end{pspicture}
 \subcaption{Before.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(\figurnummer,\hoejde)
    \pnodes{P}(0,0)(0,\bredde)(0,\hoejde)(\figurnummer,\hoejde)(\figurnummer,\bredde)(\figurnummer,0)
    \betegn{3}{7}{A}
    \betegn{3}{9}{B}
    \betegn{1}{11}{C}
    \betegn{1}{1}{D}
  {\psset{linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue}
    \multido{\iC=1+1}{\faktorC}{\psline(0,\iC)(\figurnummer,\iC)}
    \multido{\iD=1+1}{\faktorD}{\psline(\iD,0)(\iD,\hoejde)}}
   \psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \psline(P1)(P4)
    \psframe(P0)(P3)
    \psline[linejoin=1,linecolor=red](P5)(P1)(P3)
  \end{pspicture}
 \subcaption{After.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure number~$\figurnummer$ with area~$A_{\figurnummer} = \areal$.}
\end{figure}
\vspace{6ex}
}

\cfoot{\thepage}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

Test.
\newpage

\section{Appendix}
\label{appendix}
\def\sider{3}
See the figures on \autopageref{appendix}--[the value of $\texttt{\textbackslash pageref\{appendix\}} + \texttt{\textbackslash sider} - 1$].

% Figurerne.
\multido{\iE=1+2,\iF=1+1}{\sider}{%
  \multido{\iG=\iE+1}{2}{\figur{\iG}}
  \newpage
}

\end{document}
```

How do I create a counter with the value of

```
\pageref{appendix} + \sider - 1
```

? The point is that this value is equal to the page number on the last page.

Comment: have you seen [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `lastpage` package to get the value of the counter for the last page.   There is also the `pageslts` package, which the documentation for `lastpage` encourages you to use.

With `lastpage`, you can refer to the value of the last page using the command

```
\pageref{LastPage}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}` (requires `\usepackage{refcount}`) if it's needed inside `\calculate`; otherwise a run when the reference is not set will produce loads of errors.