# Using totcount with lastpage

Tags: page-numbering

My goal is to achieve n of m type page numbering if the document has more than 1 page and no page numbers otherwise. I have no problem putting n of m page numbers thanks to [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document/32537#32537). My plan was to use the [totcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package to test the total number of pages. The problem is that the [lastpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package screws up the total count. Specifically, the resulting 1 page document of the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{page}
\begin{document}
totcount: \total{page}

lastpage: \pageref{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

has `\total{page}` equal to 2 while `\pageref{LastPage}` is equal to 1.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this doesn't answer the question completely, but it provides a work-around (circumventing [`totcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/totcount)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{fancyhdr,refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyhdr,refcount}
\usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}>1
    \thepage~of~\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}

First page.

\clearpage

Last page.
\end{document}
```

If you're running into problems with unprocessed floats at the end of the document, one might have to consider using [`atveryend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend).

Comment: I like the refcount package.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `page` counter is incremented at every call of the output routine and there *is* at least a call of it when TeX decides the document has ended. So `totcount` is unreliable with `page`.

You can use `zref-lastpage` for this purpose, because it provides expandable access to the referenced value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0}>1
      \thepage\ of\ \zref@extract{LastPage}{page}%
    \fi
  }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
x

% uncommenting the following lines will show page numbers as “1 of 2” and “2 of 2”
% \clearpage
% y

\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel silly now. Of course you cannot use `totcount` with `page`, otherwise there would be no need for packages like `lastpage`. Thank you for seeing around my question and realizing that my problem was accessing the reference value.