# Resetting LastPage in scrlttr2 letters

Tags: letters, scrlttr2, lastpage

I'm trying to find a way to add "page X of Y" to the footers of my `scrlttr2` letters. At first sight, using the `lastpage` package and `\pageref*{LastPage}` works. However, as soon as multiple letters are included in the document the value of `LastPage` is equal to the number of pages in the last letter. So, if, for example I have two letters in my document, one with 2 pages followed by on of 4 pages, the "Y" above is set to 4 also in the first letter.

My first idea was to define the footers (by setting `\firstfoot` and `\nextfoot` in `\AtEndLetter{}` because at that time I can use `\thepage`. Unfortunately (and, in retrospect obviously), in that case only the last page in each letter gets the correct footer (the ones before get the default `scrlttr2` footers).

By the way, this is not a duplicate of [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/7221), I have read the answers there, but (understandably) none seem to deal with the fact that there can be more than one last page in a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new counter and then step the counter at the start of a letter and set label at the end:

```
\newcounter{Letter}
\AtBeginLetter{\stepcounter{Letter}}
\AtEndLetter{\label{lastpage\theLetter}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}
  page \thepage{} of \pageref{lastpage\theLetter}}
```

Do not use `letter` as counter name because the next KOMAScript version will define a new counter named `letter` (see the additional Information below).

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Adresse}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering \pagemark}

\newcounter{Letter}
\AtBeginLetter{\stepcounter{Letter}}
\AtEndLetter{\label{lastpage\theLetter}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}
  page \thepage{} of \pageref{lastpage\theLetter}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{letter \theLetter}
\opening{letter \theLetter}
\Blindtext
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{letter \theLetter}
\opening{letter \theLetter}
\Blindtext[20]
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

**Additional information**

I have read on the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/releasesvn) (only German) that there will be a new command `\letterlastpage` starting with **version 3.19**. Then you can simple use

```
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  page \thepage{} of \letterlastpage}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works brilliantly. I didn't think of redefining the `\pagemark`. Great to hear that there will be a command for this in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with [esdd's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255392/7221) I decided to go for the following (since I'm defining my own footers):

```
\newcounter{Letter}
\AtBeginLetter{\stepcounter{Letter}}
\AtEndLetter{\label{lastpage\theLetter}}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\thepage/\pageref*{lastpage\theLetter}}
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}
```

This prints `1/3` on the first page of a 3-page letter, etc.

The following slightly more elaborate code only prints the `X/Y` in the footer if the total number of pages (`Y`) is larger than 1.

```
\newcounter{Letter}
\AtBeginLetter{\stepcounter{Letter}}
\AtEndLetter{\label{lastpage\theLetter}}

\AtBeginLetter{%
\ifnumcomp{\getpagerefnumber{lastpage\theLetter}}{>}{1}{%
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\thepage/\pageref*{lastpage\theLetter}%
}{%
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{}}}%
}
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}
```