# scrpage2 conflict with fancyhdr

Tags: koma-script, fancyhdr, scrpage2

This is a followup to
[How can I add “page # of ##” on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282840/3406)

The MWE below works fine with the `scrpage2` line commented out, but not with. With that line uncommented, I get the error:

```
Class scrlttr2 Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrlttr2)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrlttr2)              I'd suggest to use 
(scrlttr2)              package `scrpage2' or `scrlayer-scrpage'.
(scrlttr2)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrlttr2)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 7.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command \chead already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.270 ...chead}{\@ifnextchar[{\@xchead}{\@ychead}}
```

So the `scrlttr2` recommendation is apparently to move from `fancyhdr` to something based on `scrpage2`/`scrheadings`, which I'm already using for `\rohead`. How would do this? If I get an answer, I'll update my answer to the “page # of ##” question.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}    
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\rohead{\jobname.tex\hspace{0.5cm}\today}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}

\def\today{10th December, 2015}
\begin{letter}{To Address}

  \opening{Addressee}

  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `fancyhdr` and `scrpage2` are trying to do the same functionality for you. That can't work. Use **only** one of them:  `scrpage2` or better `scrlayer-page` or `fancyhdr`.

Comment: As Kurt already noted: It's a wellknown fact that `KOMA` and `fancyhdr` do not really like each other

Comment: Yes, I get that. My attempt at replacing everything with KOMA specific stuff has not been successful, though. I guess I can add my attempts to this question.

Comment: Why would you update your answer to the other question when KOMA is not involved there? **fancyhdr** is perfectly fine. It just doesn't agree with KOMA classes/packages. I rely exclusively on **fancyhdr** but I would not if I were using KOMA.

Comment: with `scrlayer-scrpage` you probably want `\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}`

Comment: @cfr Well, it's a general question. It doesn't specify what LaTeX class is being used. Actually it doesn't even specify LaTeX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With **KOMA-Script version 3.19 or newer** and documentclass `scrlttr2` there is no need to load an additional package to get `page # of ##` in your letter(s). You only have to redefine `\pagemark` using `\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}`:

```
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \pagename\nobreakspace\thepage\nobreakspace
    of\nobreakspace\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}%
}}
```

If the page number should also be on the first page add the following line:

```
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\pagemark}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}[2015/10/03]

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\pagemark}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \pagename\nobreakspace\thepage\nobreakspace
    of\nobreakspace\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}%
}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% only for dummytext
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{date}{10th December, 2015}% note that I have changed the koma variable date instead \today

\begin{letter}{To Address}
  \opening{Addressee}
  \Blindtext[10]
  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Or with your headline:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead*{\jobname.tex\hspace{0.5cm}\usekomavar{date}}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\pagemark}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \pagename\nobreakspace\thepage\nobreakspace
    of\nobreakspace\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}%
}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% only for dummytext
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{date}{10th December, 2015}
\begin{letter}{To Address}
  \opening{Addressee}
    \Blindtext[10]
  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to print a second letter with correct pagenumbers in the same document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead*{\jobname.tex\hspace{0.5cm}\usekomavar{date}}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\pagemark}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \pagename\nobreakspace\thepage\nobreakspace
    of\nobreakspace\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}%
}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummytext
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{date}{10th December, 2015}

\begin{letter}{To Address}
  \opening{Addressee}
    \Blindtext[10]
  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{To Address}
\setkomavar{subject}{Second letter}
  \opening{Second Addressee}
    \Blindtext[20]
  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

Info for older versions: With **KOMA-Script version 3.18 or older** you have to load package `lastpage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\ohead*{\jobname.tex\hspace{0.5cm}\usekomavar{date}}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\pagemark}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \pagename\nobreakspace\thepage\nobreakspace
    of\nobreakspace\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}%
}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{date}{10th December, 2015}
\begin{letter}{To Address}

\opening{Addressee}
\Blindtext[10]
\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

Additionally here is an example for `other classes` with only one pagenumbering scheme. If you load both packages `scrlayer-scrpage` and `lastpage` you can redefine `\pagemark`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \pagename\nobreakspace\thepage\nobreakspace
    of\nobreakspace\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}%
}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting.

Comment: @Johannes_B AFAIR it has to do with  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255392/43317, see also  http://www.komascript.de/release3.19.

Comment: Does the new approach work with `\documentclass{scrartcl}`? I can't get it to; I keep getting `! Undefined control sequence.` for both `\pagename` and `\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}`. (Sorry, I'm a LaTeX newbie!)

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE Both commands are defined by the `scrlttr2` class or the package `scrletter` for usage with letters. Note that  `\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}` only works inside the `letter` environment.

Comment: Your first version, for "KOMA-Script version 3.19 or newer ", works for me with the KOMA in TeX Live 2015 (labelled as 3.19a). But you wrote "documentclass scrlttr2". Does it not work for other KOMA classes then? Anyway, thanks very much for the through answer, and accepted. Sorry I was so slow.

Comment: `\pageref{\thisletter.lastpage}` can only be used inside KOMA-Script `letter` environments. Therefore class `scrlttr2` or package `scrletter` must be loaded. If package `scrletter` is used `\letterpagemark` must be redefined instead `\pagemark`.

Comment: @esdd Ok, so the package `scrletter` is required if the `scrlttr2` class is not being used. Got it. Thanks.