# Section Number without name in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using the *fancyhdr* package to customize my header and would like to display it with the section number, but without the section name, i.e. :

```
 ______________________________________________
| Section ##                      Page #/total |
|                                              |
```

I am using the following code to custom the header:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=-.05\paperheight] at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[fill=MainColor] (0,0) rectangle
    (\paperwidth,.05\paperheight);;
    \node[anchor=west,xshift=.01\paperwidth,yshift=.025\paperheight,text width=\paperwidth]
    {\normalfont\huge\color{white}\quad{Section \leftmark}};
    \node[anchor=west,xshift=.92\paperwidth,yshift=.025\paperheight,text width=\paperwidth]
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage/\hypersetup{linkcolor=white}\pageref{LastPage}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Added MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% HEADER %
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=blue,xshift=-.5\paperwidth,yshift=-.5cm] (0,0) rectangle
(1.1\paperwidth,1.5cm);;
\node[anchor=north west,xshift=-.5\paperwidth,yshift=.5cm,text width=\paperwidth]
{\normalfont\huge\color{white}\quad{Section. \leftmark}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{blah}

\lipsum
\subsection{asdf}
\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum

    \section{blahblah}

    \lipsum

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

and it works. :)

Comment: replace `\leftmark` with `\thesection`

Comment: @touhami: That would do the trick, but when I do it, it gives the section number of the next section, i.e., for the first page of `Section 5` it prints `Section 6`. Any idea why?

Comment: where does Section 6 start? same page, next?

Comment: Please, make the code into a compilable example. In any case, you need `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection}}`

Comment: Don't nest `tikzpicture` environments. It is known to cause trouble and is not supported even though it may occasionally work. I can't see why you need one TikZ picture here - let alone two.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to include answers. This is not the way the site works. Edit your question to include an MWE. Then ask whoever helped you to write an answer which you can accept.

Comment: @egreg That worked. :) Can you please write that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @cfr removed the nested `tikzpicture`, but kep one. Any other way I could color the backgroub of the header? And I removed the solution as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the header contains just “Section 1” (or whatever the section number is), redefine `\sectionmark`:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection}}
```

(the word “Section” is already supplied by the other code). This way, `\rightmark` will contain the current section number.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\sectionmark` to suit your needs. Additionally, I've added what's needed for the `Page ##/total` (see [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/5764)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Section~\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\z@\thesection}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{blah}\lipsum

\subsection{asdf}\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\section{blahblah}\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```