# How to add page number without fancy header

Tags: page-numbering

I want to simply add page numbers to my document in the format: #page out of #pages. I find this:

```
   % This is based on the LLNCS.DEM the demonstration file of
% the LaTeX macro package from Springer-Verlag
% for Lecture Notes in Computer Science,
% version 2.4 for LaTeX2e as of 16. April 2010
%
% See http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0
% for the full guidelines.
%

\documentclass{llncs}


\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}  

\begin{document}
\cfoot{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute\\
\email{email}}

\maketitle              

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}

\end{document}
```

But it adds a line at the header. Also, it does not add number for the first page in my document. How can I solve these two issues?

Comment: Removing the header line: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` ;-) The first page is most often a `\pagestyle{empty}`, this depends on the documentclass or how the `\maketitle` etc. commands are defined. Without seeing real code, this is difficult to say.  Reading the manual is definitely a way to Enlightenment ;-)

Comment: [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I am using llncs.cls

Comment: @user2192774: Provide a compilable document then, not just fragments. My 'I'll do the work for others and glue their fragments together' -inclination is very low today ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer provided. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2192774: So your title mentions "without fancy header" yet your example code uses [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Is `fancyhdr` allowed as a solution?

Comment: @Werner: I think it is allowed since the O.P. did not know about the `\headrulewidth` command (in order to switch of the header rule), so if this obstacle is removed, `fancyhdr` **is** allowed (at least I declare it to be valid ;-))

Comment: @user2192774: [`llncs`](https://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) is for journal submission and using `runningheads` would display the necessary marks on pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: If this should be submitted to Springer, they will not accept the page number on the first page, most likely, but here you go...

`\maketitle` uses `\thispagestyle{empty}` (many document classes do so!), so either

- `\renewcommand{\maketitle}` → tedious
- Trick `\ps@empty` to be `\ps@fancy` → has to be undone later on!
- Use `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` package and replace `\thispagestyle{empty}` by nothing or by `\thispagestyle{fancy}`.

---

The next issue is the page header rule → use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to get rid off it.

The special formatting can be achieved with `lastpage` package and `\number\value{page} of \pageref{LastPage} pages}` in `\cfoot`. The `lastpage` package places the label `LastPage` (sic!!!) on -- you guess it already -- the last page!

```
\documentclass{llncs}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\number\value{page} of \pageref{LastPage} pages}
\pagestyle{fancy}  

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}{}


\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute\\
\email{email}}

\maketitle              

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: gives error: `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-basic.sty(57): Error: Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: It worked. Just noticed the packages you add. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can work with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute\\
\email{email}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]