# How to get pagecount dynamically in LaTeX?

Tags: counters

I would like to get the page count in my LaTeX document such that I do not need to do manaually do it. 
Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Page count: % TODO here

\end{document}
```

Doing the thing with `\usepackage{lastpage} ... \ref{LastPage}` puts a hyperlink (blue) there, output in Fig. 1. 
I want it without the hyperlink and in black.

Fig. 1

[image]

Comment: Package `\usepackage{lastpage}` and then in the document body:  `Page count: \pageref{Lastpage}`

Comment: This is similar in nature to [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/5764) In the link, you'll see a host of option on how to identify the last page (count).

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: use `\pageref*{LastPage}`

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: This is an often asked question and Werner linked one of them, with a bunch of answers, so it is a clear duplicate also

Comment: You should not completely change the question. Originally it was a question about how to get the number of pages. Now it is a question about how to use references without links. And you should not answer the question in the question. Questions should be questions and answers should be answers.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Yes, but I closed the question already so this is a compromise because comments can be deleted. And it is not completely changed. History always remains.