# Page border and page number in whole document

Tags: page-numbering, page

I am preparing a document having 30-40 pages and I want to add a page border in every page. How can I do this?

I also want to add page numbers like page 1 of 30.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the type(s) of page border "decorations" you're looking to achieve. Should it be a simple rectangle around the textblock, or maybe something fancier? If it's the latter, please give a sense of what you mean by "fancy".

Comment: Regarding your query, "I also want to add page numbers like page 1 of 30", do see [How can I add “page # of ##” on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/5001)

Comment: @Mico  Simple rectangle with cutting corner

Comment: In case that you only want borders on the horizontal endings of a page, take a look at the fancyhdr-package.