# How to change the page number for the scrartcl class to # of ## pages on the first page

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering

I can achieve this for the regular `article` class and the `fancyhdr` package according to an answer to question:
[How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document/282840#comment1043448_282840)

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
```

unfortunately this `fancyhdr` clashes with the `scrartcl` class and I get a recommendation to use another KOMA-Script package instead of `fancyhdr`.  Do you know what the analogue of the code above looks like for KOMA-Script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class this can be done **without a package** for header and footer.  You only have to redefine the KOMA-Script command `\pagemark`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Testing}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to add lines below the header and above the footer. If you set pagestyle `headings` you will get the sections in header.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
  headsepline,footsepline% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\pagestyle{headings}% <- added

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Testing}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to customize header and footer, you can use **package `scrlayer-scrpage`** which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Testing}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The starred version of `\ofoot` sets the entry for both `scrheadings` and `plain`.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much indeed, why does one need the \pagestyle{headings}?

Comment: You need `\pagestyle{headings}` if the section title should be in header (see page 2 of the second example).

Comment: When using `hyperref` you should use `\pageref*{LastPage}` to not create a hyperlink there on every page.

Answer (score 9):

Please see the following MWE. Important code is marked with `<=======`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  % automark places section title in header. Also enables placement in footer.
  automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage} % <=================================================

\usepackage[a4paper,
  vmargin=2cm, hmargin=2cm, % page margins
  includehead, includefoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage} % <===============================================

\ihead{\rightmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} % <=============================
\ofoot{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

It uses `scrlayer-scrpage` and `lastpage` with the following result:

[image]

Comment: Good answer! Is there anything you can do about the upright 1, it sticks out a little among all of the slanted text in the rest of the header and footer

Comment: @Au101 Ups, I oversaw that.  I changed the code and use now `\thepage` instead of `\pagemark`, which uses explicitly `\usekomafont{pagenumber}`, resulting in an different font for the current page number ...

Comment: Good job =) Looks great =) +1 from me