# How to add pages in LaTeX (for example, p.5/10)

Tags: overleaf

I am using overleaf to create reports. I would like to know if there is a way to add page numbers like p.5/10 in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Did you have a look at e.g. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_numbering#Customizing_numbering_styles

Comment: Here is a very similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/237192