# Get number of pages in document

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, automation

When writing reports it is common to have a page of meta-information at the start, written by, checked by, client, date etc. One of the fields I need is number of pages. Since I'm going to be automating the output of these reports I wondered whether there was a way of getting this from latex and then inputting it on the next compile? Something like `Number of pages: \pdflength`

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/52406) help?

Comment: See also the `totpages` package, https://ctan.org/pkg/totpages.

Answer (score 5):

Package `zref`, module `totpages` provides macro `\ztotpages` that contains the number of pages (regardless how the pages are numbered).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}

\begin{document}
Total pages: \ztotpages
\end{document}
```

Internally it works by writing a zref label to the `.aux` file.
If the label is not yet present in the `.aux` file, `\ztotpages` expands to `0`.

### Comparison last page vs. total pages

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Total pages: & \ztotpages \\
  Last page:   & \pageref{LastPage} \\
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The document contains four roman-numbered front matter pages and four main matter pages. Result:

```
Total pages: 8
Last page:   4
```

Comment: Great answer. I made a link from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document to here, so that it doesn't get lost.

Answer (score 2):

In OpTeX, there is the macro `\lastpage`. You can try:

```
\fontfam[lm]

Number of pages: \lastpage.

\bye
```

The `\lastpage` expands to `?` in the first run of TeX and terminal says:

```
WARNING l.5: Try to rerun, document.ref file was created.
```

When you run TeX again, the `\lastpage` expands to the number of pages in the document. If this number is changed, then terminal says:

```
WARNING l.9: Try to rerun, document.ref file was changed.
```

When you run TeX again, the `\lastpage` is correct and no warning is printed on the terminal and `log` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `\usepackage{lastpage}` and `\pageref{LastPage}`. Here is a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title \\
\large Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{31.05.2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{center}
    Total pages: \pageref{LastPage}
\end{center}

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```