error in using the package lastpage
I followed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32537/286173 to try to give "* of *" at the bottom of each page, but the code
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

abcd

\end{document}

gives me an error of undefined controlled sequence. So what is the problem here?
update: if I use
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

a

\end{document}

then there is a horizonal bar at the top I don't want.
If I use
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

a

\end{document}

then "* of *" is not shown.
I only want "* of *" at the bottom of each page. I don't want any other fancy stuff. Any other solutions regardless of using lastpage package is welcome!

\cfoot needs the fancyhdr package.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks. I added more content to my question.

You need to add \pagestyle{fancy} to your document preamble to force the use of the newly-defined footer. Then, to remove the rule (the default for the fancy page style header), add \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{fancy}%   <--- Added
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Add if needed

\begin{document}
a: first page
\clearpage
b: last page
\end{document}



@Werner, thank you for improving my answer!
